Confusion regarding the conversion of epsilon-NFAs to non-epsilon NFAs
I've begun reading up on NFAs and DFAs, NFAs of both the epsilon and non-epsilon kind
My understanding of epsilons are this: They help 'encode' the idea of taking another optional route without consuming input. In other words, it's a "hey, here is a free jump to another state. Just go for it without questioning why it's allowed, it's legal"
From my understanding, epsilons are just convenience at the end of the day, you could very well construct NFAs without them. I decided to try out a simple exercise, the language consisting only of the single digit: L = {1}
I'd chosen the simplest possible 'testing bed' regular expression to practice with, r = a*
In other words, this expression consists of all strings with 0 or more occurrences of a within the given language set. This can be depicted with a DFA, a single state which is both a start and acceptor state self-looping onto itself when provided a as in input
Constructing an NFA-epsilon of this, the concept of epsilon becomes very evident here, it is super convenient to encode the "0 occurrences of a" with the help of the epsilon
I then tried converting it to a non-epsilon NFA and hit a roadblock. There is no way for me to encode an input of "0 occurences of a" that should be accepted by an automation that accepts a*. From what I have read, any and all epsilon-NFAs can be converted to NFAs without epsilons. Yet this extremely simple example seems to elude me
Is it impossible to convert this epsilon-NFA to a non-epsilon NFA? I can not think of a way to encode the "0 occurences of a" input to be accepted in such a case
Am I understanding the purposes of epsilon-NFAs wrong here?

How are you drawing the $\epsilon$-NFA? Where exactly did you hit a roadblock?

By definition, all DFAs are valid NFAs. So your single state DFA is a non-$\epsilon$-NFA of the language $L = {a^*}$.

Can you add the specific example where you tried to remove $\epsilon$-transitions but failed?

To encode the 0-occurrences of $a$, we can add an initial state that is accepting. So it is hard to tell what is the example you are talking about.

It is not clear where you got stuck, but generally speaking, every $\epsilon$-NFA $A = (\Sigma, Q, Q_0, \delta, F)$ can be converted into an equivalent NFA $B$ in polynomial time.
Here is one way to do it: for every state $q$, let $E(q)$  denote the epsilon-closure of $q$; that is, $$E(q)= \{ p\in Q: \text{there is a path labeled with only $\epsilon$-transitions from $q$ to $p$ in $A$}\}$$ Note that $E(q)\subseteq Q$, and $q\in E(q)$ holds vacuously for every state $q\in Q$. Then, $B = (\Sigma,Q, S_0, \eta, F)$ is defined as:

$S_0 = \bigcup\limits_{q\in Q_0} E(q)$: so we allow ourselves not to only begin a computation at an initial state of $A$, but also at any state that is reachable from an initial state via an $\epsilon$-path.

For every state $q\in Q$, and letter $\sigma \in \Sigma$, we define $\eta(q, \sigma) = \bigcup\limits_{p\in \delta(q, \sigma)} E(p)$: also here, we allow ourselves to also proceed to all states that are reachable from the $\sigma$-successors of $q$ via an $\epsilon$-path.


The idea is simple, we essentially take the same automaton, remove epsilon transitions from it, and finally, we allow ourselves to nondeterministically  guess to not only be in a state $q$, but also be in any state in its epsilon-closure. This is what $\epsilon$-transitions mean, you can guess to be simultaneously  in any state in the epsilon-closure of the current state without reading an input letter.
To compute $B$ in polynomial-time, the only non-trivial part is to compute the set $E(q)$ for every state $q\in Q$, but this is easy as you can take the graph induced by $A$, remove every non-$\epsilon$ transition from it, and then for every state $q$, check which states are reachable from it in the resulting graph.

" so we allow ourselves not to only begin a computation at an initial state of A, but also at any state that is reachable from an initial state via an ϵ-path."
Will this not mean that such an automation could have multiple start states (if my NFA has some state q that can epsilon-transition to multiple other states)? But a DFA must not have multiple start states right?
I still can't seem to understand the intuition of why the epsilon closure helps us find the DFA, it seems arbitrary to me that the set of all states I can reach from a state q via epsilon-transitions helps me to find a DFA

@Hash Of-course you would get an NFA, as required by the question. If you want the end result to be a DFA, you can apply first $\epsilon$-removal as I described. Then, determinize the result using the subset construction a.k.a the powerset constuction. You can combine both construction as shown here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/133936/conversion-of-epsilon-nfa-to-a-dfa
But I think doing them separately gives you a better understanding if you are new to automata theory. As far as I see, my answer is sufficient as you asked only about removing epsilon transitions.
